# Update HTML tag with PHP code

Tags: php, html

What would be the easiest way to update a HTML tag with the following php code?

```
<h1>
 <?php
    include "document.txt";
    ?>
    </h1>
```

What I mean is like a timed update... every 10 second or every 2 seconds.

Comment: When? After it has already rendered to the browser? If so, you need an AJAX request to call document.text.

Comment: I have already written something like that in a function for a button! What it does is to run a PHP file.

Comment: In the simplest case [`$("h1").load(".../update.php");`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: first of all: We trust you, you do not need to defend yourself. It was asked for more information, nothing else. It's just not clear what you ask. And your comment didn't add much more information. Personally I would like to see a picture of you, but you don't need to post that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). jQuery has a really easy to use function to make AJAX requests, see [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

This example (modified from the jQuery page) is what you want:

```
function loadData() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "document.txt",
      cache: false
    }).done(function( html ) {
      $("#results").html(html);
    });
}
```

It'll get the contents of the `document.txt` file and add it to an element with the attribute `id="results"` like the following:

```
<h1 id="results"></h1>
```

You can then use [`window.setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) to execute the code at a set interval.

```
window.setInterval(loadData, 10000);
```